# Updating Route 53 automatically when Auto Scaling brings up new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, autoscaling

I am using Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling in my environment, whenever Auto Scaling triggers a new instance, I need to change the IP manually in Route 53. I want to automate this process.

Tried using [Lifecycle Hooks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-with-auto-scaling-lifecycle-hooks/) but didn't see any update for Route 53.

Comment: How many instances are in your Auto Scaling group? Updating the IP address makes sense if Auto Scaling is only providing a single instance, but if you are using more than one instance, please tell us how you would be managing the IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
# !/bin/bash

INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
PRIVATE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
DOMAIN_NAME=$(aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id "<Hosted Zone ID >" --query 'HostedZone.Name' --output text | sed 's/.$//')

hostnamectl set-hostname hostname."${DOMAIN_NAME}"

CN=`echo $PRIVATE_IP | cut -d . -f 3`

echo $CN
a=5
if [ $CN == $a ]

then

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "<Hosted Zone ID >" --change-batch '{"Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "'"Dns Name"'","Type": "A","TTL": 60,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "'"${PRIVATE_IP}"'"}]}}]}'

else

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "<Hosted Zone ID >" --change-batch '{"Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "'"< Dns Name>"'","Type": "A","TTL": 60,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "'"${PRIVATE_IP}"'"}]}}]}'

fi
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I have posted the final solution.

Comment: can you explain the CN= part ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this User Data script to update the Route 53 record when an instance is launched.

It gathers required information from Instance Metadata.

```
#!
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
PRIVATE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
DOMAIN_NAME=$(aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id "${HOSTED_ZONE_ID}" --query 'HostedZone.Name' --output text | sed 's/.$//')

hostnamectl set-hostname hostname."${DOMAIN_NAME}"

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "${HOSTED_ZONE_ID}" --change-batch '{"Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "'"$(hostname)"'","Type": "A","TTL": 60,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "'"${PRIVATE_IP}"'"}]}}]}'
```

You would need to insert a value for the `${HOSTED_ZONE_ID}` to identify the record to update.

**EDIT:**

If You have multiple instances provisioned by ASG, You can develop a script to name new host.
I.e:

1. Use ASG to apply "role" TAG to every instance provisioned by ASG i.e *role=webserver*
2. In userdata script list all instances with TAG *role=webserver*
3. Check returned instances for TAG "node"
4. If none, then this instance is node1 -> hostname webserver-node1.${DOMAIN_NAME}
5. If some, parse TAG "node" to check which instance was replaced by ASG. I.e in result you can have node=node1, node=node3, node=node4. node2 is missing, so this instance is node2 -> hostname webserver-node2.${DOMAIN_NAME}
6. At the end of userdata you have to add "node" TAG to this instance, so next one is not named as existing one.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, thanks for the reply. I am using autoscaling group how can i use this for new instances which are spinning up. Is this script useful for such conditions?

Comment: @ John this is useful, but in my case, I have 2 servers attached to my Autoscaling group in diff availability zone 2a and 2b . If i add this as user-data in ASG.. I can only give one hostname.

Comment: You have to implement host naming script.